# How to compile different c files with different CFLAGS using Makefile?

Tags: makefile

all. Let's say I have a program that contains a long list of C source files, A.c, B.c, ...., Z.c, now I want to compile A.c, B.c with certain CFLAGS, and compile the rest part of source files with a different CFLAGS value.

How to write a Makefile to do the above described job? currently what I am doing in my Makefile is:

```
OBJ=[all other .o files here, e.g. D.o, D.o, E.o .... Z.o]
SPECIAL_OBJS=A.o B.o

all: $(OBJ) $(SPECIAL_OBJS)

$(SPECIAL_OBJS): 
     @echo [Compiling]: $(@:.o=.c)
     $(CC) [SOME OTHER GCC OPTIONS HERE] $(CFLAGS) -c $(@:.o=.c) -o $@

%.o: %.c
     @echo [Compiling]: $<
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

It works, but looks just stupid/complicated. Can anyone help to point out what is the recommended way of doing this in Makefile? thanks!

Comment: Is this Posix Make or GNU Make?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try using target-specific variables. A target-specific variable is declared like this:

```
TARGET: VAR := foo  # Any valid form of assignment may be used ( =, :=, +=, ?=)
```

Now when the target named TARGET is being made, the variable named VAR will have the value "foo".

Using target-specific variables, you could do this, for example:

```
OBJ=[all other .o files here, e.g. D.o, D.o, E.o .... Z.o]
SPECIAL_OBJS=A.o B.o

all: $(OBJ) $(SPECIAL_OBJS)

$(SPECIAL_OBJS): EXTRA_FLAGS := -std=c99   # Whatever extra flags you need

%.o: %.c
     @echo [Compiling]: $<
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: If you don't want to re-define the default .c -> .o compilation rule, an `CFLAGS+=$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)` would work as well (at least for GNU make).

Comment: Directly appending to CFLAGS seems to also work: `$(SPECIAL_OBJS): CFLAGS+=-std=c99` (GNU make again).

Comment: @sstn As noted above, any valid form of assignment may be used.

Comment: sorry, skipped through that.

Comment: It's worth noting the extra info here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/978065/2757035 - that target-specific variables have the "special feature" that they are applied to rules for dependencies of their target, too, unless overridden by said dependencies. Presuming, based on the wording "special feature", that the method used by the Linux kernel as shown by Mykyta doesn't do this - then there might be some situations (for which imagination fails me) where it's nice to have both options.

Answer (score 16):

The approach taken by linux kernel build system:

```
CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS-$@)
```

And then,

```
CFLAGS-A.o += -DEXTRA
CFLAGS-B.o += -DEXTRA
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the question for raw makefiles, but if you are willing to use automake it is trivial:

```
foo_CFLAGS = [options passed to CC only when building foo]
```

Comment: When using automake like this, can "foo" be any kind of target (e.g. object file), or does it have to be a final target (executable or library)?

Comment: Using primaries like this applies to final targets and all intermediate targets.  To apply only to intermediate targets (eg .o files), you can write explicit rules into the Makefile.am