# Per-file CPPFLAGS in Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, android-source

I'm working on an Android.mk file in which, for a single module, one of the files needs different CPPFLAGS; namely, it needs -frtti enabled, while others need the Android default of -fno-rtti.

The obvious solution was [target-specific variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1305665/253526), but oddly they do not seem to affect compilation, even with some fiddling to ensure the values should be fixed at the right time.

Here's an extract from my Android.mk (names changed to protect me):

```
LOCAL_MODULE := foo_bar

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    foo_bar.cpp \
    foo_baz.cpp

my_intermediates:= $(local-intermediates-dir)/foo_baz.o
$(my_intermediates): LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -frtti
```

I have tried simply doing `foo_baz.o:` in lieu of $(my_intermediates), and have tried substituting `+=` for `:=` to no change.

So, is there an Android-specific way to override CPPFLAGS (or CFLAGS) for a specific source file?

(In this case I'm using the Eclair Android sources, though it may apply to the NDK; see my answer, below.)

Comment: Seems the `local-intermediates-dir` macro is gone (I have NDK r9b). What would be the replacement?

Comment: did you find the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is usual, having asked the question after spending a lot of time on it, I have found the answer in short order. I need to use `PRIVATE_CPPFLAGS` instead of `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`.

However, this only appears to be the case for the Android source distribution (at least Eclair) and NDK r6b. If I was using NDK r6, this probably would have worked as it stands.

Comment: A code example of the technique you used would be useful. The [Android.mk docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk) don't appear to discuss it.

Comment: This was nearly 7 years ago, and I've not needed to do it in that time. If someone has an working example of this technique for a modern NDK but not general editing powers, please comment with the information or a link to a gist, and I will edit it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have different parameters for some source files is to group these files in Android.mk together to produce a static library `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` which will then be listed in `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` for the resulting shared object.