# Adding a compiler flag to only one file in Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android.mk

I have an Android.mk file that has a number of files for which LOCAL_CFLAGS get applied to them. I would like to apply a different flag to only one of the files out of the many. How can this be accomplished?

I searched the internet from the Android perspective, but didn't find a whole lot. Considering the following example I would like to apply flag `TEST3` to file `test3.c` only. I looked at [Per-file CPPFLAGS in Android.mk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447836/per-file-cppflags-in-android-mk), but I couldn't find anything as far as how to use `PRIVATE_CPPFLAGS` to one file. Any ideas?

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test1.c test2.c test3.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST1_2_AND_3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Ok, so the link does indicate how to use PRIVATE_CPPFLAGS, but when I try it and LOCAL_CPPFLAGS I get:  LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS not defined before call to local-intermediates-dir.  Stop. Any ideas?

Comment: If the TAG name is different, then you can use the specific one in the specific file but no any impact to other files. it's not so meaningful to do such private flags mechanism. More complicated and less benefit.

Answer (score 2):

The supported way to achieve your goal is to use a separate static library for C/CPP files that need different parameters. In this particular case, the fix would be as easy as

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

LOCAL_MODULE := test3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test3.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST1_2_AND_3 -DTEST3
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test1.c test2.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST1_2_AND_3
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := test3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

There is another approach, similar to one I [forged a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12234755/192373)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

TARGET-process-src-files-tags += $(call add-src-files-target-cflags, $(LOCAL_TEST3_SRC_FILES), $(LOCAL_TEST3_CFLAGS))

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test1.c test2.c test3.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST1_2_AND_3

LOCAL_TEST3_SRC_FILES := test3.c
LOCAL_TEST3_CFLAGS := -DTEST3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If **`-Dtest3`** would do, you can use another hack:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

get-src-file-target-cflags = $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES_TARGET_CFLAGS.$1) -D$(basename $1)_DEFINE

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test1.c test2.c test3.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DTEST1_2_AND_3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

See more in *[How to dynamically get the current compiler target file name in Android.mk's LOCAL_CFLAGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36744976/192373)*.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to need a little time to test these methods.