# How to dynamically get the current compiler target file name in Android.mk's LOCAL_CFLAGS?

Tags: android, c, makefile, android-ndk, android.mk

I am currently trying to build a native module using Android's NDK. My project consists of several source files (e.g.: **FILENAME**.c) and for each of them I need to declare a define in their CFLAGS (**-DOPERATION_FILENAME**).

In order to do that I need to dynamically fetch the name of the current target file of the Android NDK's cross-compiler and use it to for the define value.

I could not find any information about how to do this and the Makefile way (**CFLAGS += -DOPERATION_`echo $* | sed 's/_$$//'`**) does not apply/work here.

My current Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_MODULE := libmpn

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
<cut>

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
-std=gnu99 \
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H \
-D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP \
-O2 \
-pedantic \
-fomit-frame-pointer \
-mfloat-abi=softfp \
-DOPERATION_`echo $* | sed 's/_$$//'`

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Does anyone know of a working way to get the file name of the current cross-compiler target in Android.mk? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning of your **Android.mk**, add the line that redefines **get-src-file-target-cflags**, like here:

```
get-src-file-target-cflags = $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES_TARGET_CFLAGS.$1) -DOPERATION_$(basename $1)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := t.cpp qq.c
LOCAL_MODULE := tm
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -latomic

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You can put this line in **Application.mk**, if you choose.

Comment: Wouldn't this break a windows-based NDK build?

Comment: @gladed I don't know why this could be different on Windows. But this hack depends on implementation details that can break in the new release of NDK.

Comment: `basename` isn't available in Windows (unless you build inside Cygwin).

Comment: The choice of $basename for flags was a transient implementation detail. How hard is it to write a regexp to emulate basename? The idea that CFLAGS should be different for each file was important.