# arm thumb mode code generation -- gcc arm linux compiler

Tags: gcc, arm

I have a question for ARM thumb mode. Does GCC arm linux compiler generates thumb mode code on it own ?
Or we have to use some compiler directive to tell compiler to generate thumb mode code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to switch between both modes as appropriate but -mthumb overrides it. The list of ARM options may be found here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: -mthumb  --->> this should go in makefile ..??? for those files which we want to compile using thumb mode ...????

Comment: Yes you probably want something like here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305665/how-to-compile-different-c-files-with-different-cflags-using-makefile. I'm not a real makefile person I normally use Eclipse and other IDEs.