# Iterating over lists in Makefiles - revisited

Tags: loops, foreach, gnu-make

I liked the answer Dylan gave to the question, "Iterating over lists in Makefiles", 
[Iterating over lists in Makefiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977933/iterating-over-lists-in-makefiles) and tried to do something similar but am having trouble. Perhaps sonmeone could help.

my Makefile:

```
PARTITION_TMP:=Joe|red \
               Carl:Mary|white \
               Fritz|blue

partition_tmp:
    @- $(foreach partition_tmp,$(PARTITION_TMP), \
        $(eval N = $(word 1, $(subst |, ,$(partition_tmp)))) \
        $(eval C = $(word 2, $(subst |, ,$(partition_tmp)))) \
        $(call print_tmp, $N, $C) \
    )

define print_tmp
    @echo in print_tmp
    @echo set_global -name PARTITION_NAME $(1)
    @echo set_global -color PARTITION_COLOR $(2) -name PARTITION_NAME $(1)
endef
```

When I run make, I get the following:

> in print_tmp
>
> set_global -name PARTITION_NAME Joe
>
> set_global -color PARTITION_COLOR red -name PARTITION_NAME Joe @echo
>   in print_tmp
>
> set_global -name PARTITION_NAME Carl:Mary
>
> set_global -color PARTITION_COLOR white -name PARTITION_NAME Carl:Mary
>   @echo in print_tmp
>
> set_global -name PARTITION_NAME Fritz
>
> set_global -color PARTITION_COLOR blue -name PARTITION_NAME Fritz

I can't figure out why I'm getting the "@echo in print_tmp" at the end of the first two calls to print_tmp (or maybe it's the beginning of the last two calls to print_tmp?)

Can someone help?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're stringing together `print_tmp` blocks on a single line-- but the blocks have internal line breaks. Consider:

```
partition_tmp:
    $(foreach color, red blue, \
  $(call print_tmp, $(color)) \
  )

define print_tmp
    @echo first $(1)
endef
```

The `foreach` evaluates to `@echo first red @echo first blue`, which is then executed as a shell command and produces:

```
first red @echo first blue
```

Now add another line to the macro:

```
partition_tmp:
    $(foreach color, red blue, \
  $(call print_tmp, $(color)) \
  )

define print_tmp
    @echo first $(1)
    @echo second $(1)
endef
```

Now the `foreach` evaluates to

```
@echo first red 
@echo second red @echo first blue
@echo second blue
```

which produces:

```
first red 
second red @echo first blue
second blue
```

To correct the problem, just add a blank line:

```
define print_tmp
    @echo in print_tmp
    @echo set_global -name PARTITION_NAME $(1)
    @echo set_global -color PARTITION_COLOR $(2) -name PARTITION_NAME $(1)

endef
```